# Visualise correctly Paper-Icon-Button's images with Polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

I've been having problems trying to work with paper-icon-button with Polymer. My code so far is very simple. The website generates the space that the icon uses and reacts with the right behaviour to respond to the mouse's events but the icon doesn't show up

```
<paper-toolbar class="gallery_header">
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <span title class="flex">Admin</span>
</paper-toolbar>
```

The scripts that are being loaded in order are:
webcomponentsjs
polymer
iron-icon
bootstrap
iron-ajax
iron-image
paper-drawer-panel
jquery
paper-header-panel
paper-styles
paper-icon-button
paper-toolbar
react

Comment: hope when you say script you mean `script` for `js` file and `link` tag for `html`. You will also need to load `iron-icons` as that is where your `menu` icon is present.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do extra in order to make that menu icon appear is to import the `iron-icons` [element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-icons) which is just a collection of SVG icons. For more information about the iconsets and the `iron-icons` element, you can check out Rob Dodson's episode [on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kkNgVG6LuI) from the Polycasts series.